# Semantic ui table within grid

Tags: html-table, semantic-ui

When we add a table within a grid it forces the next column to flow underneath and then you can't control your display for different devices sizes. Does anyone knows how to fix this?

```
<div class="ui grid">
        <div class="sixteen wide mobile eight wide tablet four wide computer column">
            <p>1 row mobile - 2 tablet - 4 computer</p>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="sixteen wide mobile eight wide tablet four wide computer column">
            <p>1 row mobile - 2 tablet - 4 computer</p>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="sixteen wide mobile eight wide tablet four wide computer column">
            <p>1 - row mobile - 2 tablet - 4 computer</p>
        </div>
        <div class="sixteen wide mobile eight wide tablet four wide computer column">
            <p>1 - row mobile - 2 tablet - 4 computer</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Try removing the second table and you will see that it will replace itself properly.
When you run the debug in chrome you see that it changes the class where the table is contained to:

Before
    sixteen wide mobile eight wide tablet four wide computer column

After
    sixteen wide mobile eight tablet four computer column

Comment: I [can't seem to reproduce this](http://jsfiddle.net/fstanis/mjftzw7h/1/). The columns work fine when the *Result* area is resized. Can you explain better what's supposed to happen?

Comment: Thanks for checking on this.

I realized last night that the issue was caused by the Meteor framework that was removed duplicated style name in the class (eg: sixteen and wide) as Meteor states that you should not have 2 class with the same name